# Nginx redirect for single page on single subdomain while using wildcard subdomains

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a server block that uses wildcard subdomains, example *.example.com. I need to redirect a single page on a single subdomain to a different page, while processing all other requests normally. What's the most efficient way to handle this?

Server block looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    ....
}
```

And I need this behavior:

http://baseball.example.com/test.php -> http://baseball.example.com/new-page

http://football.example.com/test.php -> no redirect

http://basketball.example.com/test.php -> no redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way, from a processing perspective, would be to create a separate `server` block for the special case. As most of the configuration would be the same for both server blocks, you could use an `include` statement to read it from a separate file.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    include /path/to/common.config;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name baseball.example.com;
    location = /test.php {
        return 301 /new-page;
    }
    include /path/to/common.config;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: Good idea, I think this is the best option. Thanks for the tip!